# How to fix this dll loading python error?

Tags: python

I use one c++ dll in my python code.
When I run my python app on my computer, it works fine but when I copy all to another computer this happen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\users\Public\SoundLog\Code\Código Python\SoundLog\SoundLog.py", line 9, in <module>
   from Auxiliar import *
 File "C:\users\Public\SoundLog\Code\Código Python\SoundLog\Auxiliar\DataCollection.py", line 4, in <module>
   import SoundLogDLL
 File "C:\users\Public\SoundLog\Code\Código Python\SoundLog\Auxiliar\SoundLogDLL.py", line 4, in <module>
   dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.environ['PUBLIC'] + "\\SoundLog\\DLLs\\ForPython\\SoundLogC++WrapperDLL.dll")
 File "C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
   return self._dlltype(name)
 File "C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
   self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail
```

How can I fix this problem so that my python app work in every computer?

Note:
I only need them to work on windows 7 like mine. And I tested on another win7 computer (both 32bits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a DLL which depends on a Microsoft Visual C++ runtime which isn't installed on the target computer. You have a few options:

- Install or copy the Visual C++ runtime libraries to the target computer. Installation is done by adding merge modules to your installer (if you have one) or by running the redistributable installer (`vcredist.exe`). The various methods are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235316%28VS.80%29.aspx) for VS2005 (other versions will be similar).
- If you built the DLL, you can change the project settings to statically link the runtime libraries. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230/how-do-you-pack-a-visual-studio-c-project-for-release/5321#5321) to see how this is done.

Comment: Specifically, the ctypes library. I'm not sure how much Windows supports it.

Comment: @Bryan: Windows supports the ctypes library just fine. The error here was not caused by ctypes, but by a DLL which happened to have been loaded using ctypes.

Comment: I've done it installing the Visual C++ runtime libraries and changing the execution of the project from Debug to Release ^^