# Why some Winapp without C++ Redistributable Package?

Tags: visual-c++

Many Winapp install by without C++ Redistributable Package?

They want Windows installer only.

How to programming by without C++ Redistributable Package runtime?

Please explain ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use static link? Look here
[How do you pack a visual studio c++ project for release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230/how-do-you-pack-a-visual-studio-c-project-for-release)