# build gdcm 2.4.1 with cmake and msvc 2010 can't get all the dlls

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, gdcm

I build the gdcm following the [instruction](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Configuring_and_Building_With_VS_.NET_2008_%28Include_C_sharp_wrapping%29), no c# wrapping, with GDCM_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS checked (using the cmake-gui), after configured and generated, open the msvc2010 and buildall, 
I find the content of the `build_dir\bin\debug` are all static libs, but where is the dlls? I know little about the cmake, only know how to use the cmake_gui, the problem drives me crazy, any help is appreciated. I have built the gdcm with msvc2008 successfully and it works well, with the dlls generated in the `build_dir\bin\debug` or `build_dir\bin\release`.

Comment: I know this version of gdcm works for static libs and Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 since I target my applications with that. Although I have not tried building any version of GDCM with GDCM_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS in a long time.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you for your concern, I tried to use the static libs, following this [tips](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8749234/930125) and include the header files. but I contantly got the unresolved link error, and I don't know why

Comment: All of my applications that I develop use CMake to generate the Visual Studio (+ linux when I have time to make a port) project files so I never mess with project settings directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should read the tuturial of cmake first, I checked the GDCM_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS, but forgot to reconfigure it, sorry for the foolishness.

Comment: how did you reconfigured it .I'm facing the same problem I never used cmake before..

Comment: @Optimus you need to click the configure button twice